# How do I prevent apt from attempting to update a manually configured and installed package?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, nginx

I have a custom NGINX setup (some additional 3rd party modules), and I don't want Ubuntu to think it needs to be 'updated' to its version that doesn't have the modules I need.  How do I stop Ubuntu from attempting to update it?  Is it as simple as:

`$ sudo apt-mark hold nginx`

Or is there more to it?

EDIT: I'm using 1.13.1, so by version number my version is newer than what's in the Ubuntu repos, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, `sudo apt-mark hold nginx` is what I would do as well to prevent any automatic actions on that specific package, like upgrades.